# Bitlocker corruption in dual-boot

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker

Steps i took to end up with this corruption:

- Installed Windows 10 Pro 20H2 (from now on Windows#1) in a freshly cleaned GPT drive. Did all updates, programs setup and it was all good.
- Activated Bitlocker on Windows#1 volume (XTS-AES, full encryption, did the pre-encryption reboot test). All good, test successful and then got the drive fully encrypted.
- Shrank the Windows#1 Bitlocker volume by 256 GB (down from 1TB).
- Installed Windows 10 Pro 1809V2 (Windows#2) in this newly unallocated space. Successful and working. At this point Windows#2 is also the default boot option.

Then i activated Bitlocker on Windows#2 volume. As before i choose XTS-AES, full encryption and to do the pre-encryption reboot test, except this time i was greeted at reboot with the Bitlocker recovery page which asked for the numerical recovery password, only for it to instantly reboot when i tried to enter it (correctly 100%).
At this point i was sure something bad happened and feared for the Windows#1, but after a reboot i was able to log into that installation without issue.
Inside Windows#1 i did some troubleshooting, and here is the output (`C:` being Windows#1 and `H:` being Windows#2):

```
manage-bde -status

Volume C: [system]
[OS Volume]

    Size:                 697,27 GB
    BitLocker Version:    2.0
    Conversion Status:    Fully Encrypted
    Percentage Encrypted: 100,0%
    Encryption Method:    XTS-AES 128
    Protection Status:    Protection On
    Lock Status:          Unlocked
    Identification Field: Unknown
    Key Protectors:
        TPM
        Numerical Password

Volume H: [Label Unknown]
[Data Volume]

    Size:                 Unknown GB
    BitLocker Version:    2.0
    Conversion Status:    Unknown
    Percentage Encrypted: Unknown%
    Encryption Method:    XTS-AES 128
    Protection Status:    Unknown
    Lock Status:          Locked
    Identification Field: Unknown
    Automatic Unlock:     Disabled
    Key Protectors:
        TPM
        Numerical Password
```

```
repair-bde H: C:\image.img -rp XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX -Force

BitLocker Drive Encryption: Repair Tool version 10.0.19041
Copyright (C) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Beginning scan for BitLocker metadata.

Scanning boot sectors for pointer to metadata: 100%
Scanning sector boundaries for metadata:   1%
LOG ERROR: 0xc0000033
Failed to authenticate using supplied recovery information. (0x80070057)
LOG ERROR: 0xc000003b
Could not validate metadata at offset 67616768. (0x80070057)
LOG ERROR: 0xc0000033
Failed to authenticate using supplied recovery information. (0x80070057)
LOG ERROR: 0xc000003b
Could not validate metadata at offset 1140850688. (0x80070057)
LOG ERROR: 0xc0000033
Failed to authenticate using supplied recovery information. (0x80070057)
LOG ERROR: 0xc000003b
Could not validate metadata at offset 2214592512. (0x80070057)
Scanning sector boundaries for metadata:   2%
LOG WARNING: 0x8000003a
Proper metadata signature found, but the metadata is invalid. (0x80310010)
LOG ERROR: 0xc000003b
Could not validate metadata at offset 7303756288. (0x80310010)
Scanning sector boundaries for metadata: 100%
Finished scanning for BitLocker metadata.

ERROR: Cannot use 'XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX' to
unlock the input volume. Please try a different recovery password, recovery key
or password.
```

The numerical recovery password used in both the boot page and with `repair-bde` is absolutely correct, no chance of confusion here.

One additional thing i tried is switch the default Windows boot, but it didn't change anything.

I am completely at a loss here. I know Bitlocker is a bit quirky but i always expected the recovery keys to work (and they did up until now every time i needed to use them, even on catastrophic failures).

PS: just want to add that no data is being lost here, only hours of installing and setting up the OS and applications.

Comment: I have never heard of enabling BitLocker on two different installations when installed and on the same disk.  If it’s saying the incorrect recovery key was provided then that’s the case

Comment: I have found other instances of the same issue (with nearly identical premises) here `https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c657f083-8070-4f2e-9fbf-92f8e3591e5d/bitlocker-aesxts-failure?forum=win10itprogeneral`. Unfortunately the solution of the last guy didn't work for me. As for the key, again there is 0% chance of user error: it has been copy-pasted from the TXT file created by the wizard just hours ago in my removable USB. ID matches, key is not correct (or better yet, i'd say at this point bitlocker just doesn't recognize the key anymore because it got corrupted).

Comment: I am not saying it’s user error, I am saying BitLocker believes that’s the case, which is all that matters

Comment: After more troubleshooting, i was still not able to recover the volume, so i went ahead and deleted it to start over. I was then able to make the planned configuration (dual boot on the same drive with bitlocker on both volumes) work by switching from TPM to boot time password. So my guess is the specific TPM on my board trips on this kind of configuration.